# format floating point number to a char array of limited size with optional decimal point

Tags: c++, formatting, c++17

I need to print out floating point numbers to a fixed number of chars.  This is used in a strictly text-based data protocol (yes I know).  Decimal is inclusive in character count.  Ignore null terminator.  There is no min padding requirement.  Decimal precision can be 0 to (buffer size - 2) while max number of real numbers can be 0 to buffer size.  Min and max value clamping to prevent truly out of range numbers are handled externally to this problem.

Examples with the assumption of a buffer size of 6 with enforcing min and max values of (0.0001 and 999999):

| Original | Buffer (6 chars) | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12445.11897784 | 12445 | Only the 5 digts are kept as there is no room for decimal + value |
| 8846.51548 | 8846.5 |  |
| 4.54631888315 | 4.5463 |  |
| 7651 | 7651 |  |
| 0.87457 | .87457 | 0.8746 would also be acceptable |

I thought sprintf with %.6G seemed to work at first until I realized it did not factor in the decimal point as a character.  Is my understanding incomplete?

Is there any utilities in C++17 or lower I can use to accomplish the above.  I am also willing to consider libraries that will or have become part of the standard in versions greater than c++17.

Comment: `Is my understanding incomplete?` What is your understanding?

Comment: Consider `snprintf`.

Comment: `Is there any utilities in C++17` Are you looking for utilities or do you want to solve your problem?

Comment: [{fmt}](https://fmt.dev) is becoming quite popular these days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a C++ 17 version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <charconv>

std::string to6(float f) {
    std::string s;
    s.resize(10);
    auto ec = std::to_chars(s.data(), s.data() + s.size(), f, std::chars_format::fixed);
    s.resize(6);
    if (s.back() == '.')
        s.resize(5);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << to6(12445.11897784) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to6(8846.51548) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to6(4.54631888315) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to6(7651) << std::endl;
    std::cout << to6(0.87457) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I didn't check for errors, as

> Min and max value clamping to prevent truly out of range numbers are handled externally to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward:

1. If number is greater then 10000

   1. Print it normally with no digits `%.0f`
2. If a number is greater then 1000

   1. Print with one digit after comma `%.1f`
3. If a number is greater then 100

   1. Print with two digits after comma `%.2f`
4. If a number is greater then 10
   2. Print with 3 digits after comma `%.3f`
5. if ... 1

   1. ... `%.4f`
6. else

   1. `%.5f`
   2. Remove leading zero

Be ware of rounding! Ex. number 9.999999 is lower then 10, however it will get printed as 10.000. Because of that:

1. First print the number with greatest precision needed - `%.5f` - into a string.
2. Then count the digits before comma **in the resulting string**.
3. Then do the above comparisons "if a number is greater then 100" on the *count* of digits before the comma, rather then the actual number.
4. Trim the string to the needed count of digits after a comma.

Ie. work on the correctly rounded number that is in a string after printing, not before printing, that way you protect against any rounding changing your number while converting to a string.